# Keep Checkbox Status of DataGrid with Pagination

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have a windows desktop application. On one form, I use a datagrid to show some data from database. Since there are many rows, I added pagination to the datagrid. Basically, when on different pages, query the database for the data that should be shown in that page, then bind it as data source. This works great. However, it does not keep the checkbox status.

For example, on page 1, I checked 3 rows, then, go to page 2, then go back to page 1, the checkboxes are reset.

I had this issue before in one asp.net application. The fix is to use Session to save the status. I

In this case, I can do the similar thing using public property.

My question is: is there a simpler way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: to clarify, the checkbox, I mean the checkbox for each row in the datagrid. It does not come from the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just get the datasources only once when a page is being viewed for the first time? Then you would have a datasource for each page. Then when the page changes you just swap the datasource to corresponding one. After saving I'd reload all of the datasources.